# joining every 4th line in csv-file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'd like to join every 4th line together so I thought something like this would work:

```
import csv

filename = "mycsv.csv"
f = open(filename, "rb")

new_csv = []
count = 1

for i, line in enumerate(file(filename)):
    line = line.rstrip()
    print line
    if count % 4 == 0:
        new_csv.append(old_line_1 + old_line_2 + old_line_3+line)
    else:
        old_line_1 = line[i-2]
        old_line_2 = line[i-1]
        old_line_3 = line
    count += 1

print new_csv
```

But `line[i-1]` and `line[i-2]` does not take current line -1 and -2 as I thought. So how can I access current line -1 and -2?

Comment: No, no, no. Don't use `enumerate` function. It can be very dangerous. At first, use `with` statement and then look at [csv built-in library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: @HonzaSedloň what's with the statement *Don't use enumerate function. It can be very dangerous* - it doesn't make much sense...?

Comment: @HonzaSedloň How exactly is `enumerate()` dangerous (in itself)?

Comment: There is always a better way then using `enumerate()`.

Comment: @HonzaSedloň Please explain what you believe is dangerous about `enumerate`.  It's a very useful function and not intrinsically dangerous (of course it can be combined with other code that _is_ dangerous, just like any Python language element can be).

Comment: @HonzaSedloň: that's the most *absurd* accusation I have yet to come across. Why is `enumerate()` *dangerous*? All it does is add an increasing counter to an iterable. Please provide some proof.

Comment: Well, I've never used it before. And why? I heard thousand times that it could be dangerous. I know, it's not a proof. In the book, heard from people, ...

Comment: I am glad this raised a discussion because I use `enumerate()` pretty often, and I will continue doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `line` contains only the line for the current iteration, so accessing `line[i-1]` will only give you one character within the current line. [The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45709203/1782792) is probably the tersest way to put it but, building on your code, you could do something like this instead:

```
import csv

filename = "mycsv.csv"
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    new_csv = []
    lines = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        line = line.rstrip()
        lines.append(line)
        if (i + 1) % 4 == 0:
            new_csv.append("".join(lines))
            lines = []

print new_csv
```

Comment: Instead of enumerating from 0 and doing `(i + 1) % 4 == 0`, you could just start enumerating at 1: `enumerate(open(filename), 1)`.

Comment: Do you mind explaining  `lines = []`on row 8 and then again on 14?

Comment: @destinychoice Sure, and also I fixed a mistake. The first time you are just creating an empty list _before_ even starting to read the file. Every line that you read you add it to this `lines` list. Then, when you reach a multiple of 4 you [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the strings in the list and append the result to `new_csv`; then the list `lines` is cleared (made it empty again) so in the next iteration you start with the next block of four lines.

Comment: @poke Umh, right, that was just copy/pasted from the OP but I've cleaned up the code a bit in that too anyway.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should do as you require

```
join_every_n = 4
all_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file(filename)]  # note the OP uses some unknown func `file` here
transposed_lines = zip(*[all_lines[n::join_every_n] for n in range(join_every_n)])
joined = [''.join([l1,l2,l3,l4]) for (l1,l2,l3,l4) in transposed_lines]
```

likewise you could also do

```
joined = map(''.join, transposed_lines)
```

## Explanation

This will return every i'th element in a `your_list` with an offset of `n`

```
your_list[n::i]
```

Then you can combine this across a `range(4)` to generate for every 4 lines in a list such that you get

```
[[line0, line3, ...], [line1, line4, ...], [line2, line6, ...], [line3, line7, ...]]
```

Then the `transposed_lines` is required to transpose this array so that it becomes like

```
[[line0, line1, line2, line3], [line4, line5, line6, line7], ...]
```

Now you can simple unpack and join each individual list element

## Example

```
all_lines = map(str, range(100))
transposed_lines = zip(*[all_lines[n::4] for n in range(4)])
joined = [''.join([l1,l2,l3,l4]) for (l1,l2,l3,l4) in transposed_lines]
```

gives

```
['0123',
 '4567',
 '891011',
...
```

Comment: `TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (4 given)`

Comment: @destinychoice I've fixed and explained

Comment: The same one as the magic `file` function in the OP `for i, line in enumerate(file(filename)):` See the example for a non-magic `file` function - I'll add a note to clarify

Comment: FWIW, the `file` callable is an ancient deprecated way of opening files. It's not a function, it's the constructor for `file` objects. You can read about it in [the Python 2.2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html#tex2html11). The 2.2 docs recommend `file()` over `open()`, by 2.4 the recommendation was to use `open` for opening and `file` for type testing. And of course `file` no longer exists in Python 3.